# ZFS and USB boot on Pi4b 8Gb

Tags: usb, pi-4, kernel, ubuntu, 64-bit

I'm trying to make myself a NAS appliance with a Pi4b 8Gb. I would like to use ZFS for my storage but I'm having some trouble with installing it on pi OS.
I'm trying to use USB boot (No SD) so I can get the speed advantages of booting from an SSD and this works fine with pi OS 64bit.
An answer to how to install ubuntu 20.04 with No SD card and USB boot or how to install zfs on raspberry pi OS 64bit would solve my problem.

The prebuilt zfs-dkms module does not install correctly:

```
Preconfiguring packages ...                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Selecting previously unselected package zfs-dkms.                                                                                                                                                                                       
(Reading database ... 110181 files and directories currently installed.)                                                                                                                                                                
Preparing to unpack .../zfs-dkms_0.7.12-2+deb10u2_all.deb ...                                                                                                                                                                           
Unpacking zfs-dkms (0.7.12-2+deb10u2) ...                                                                                                                                                                                               
Selecting previously unselected package zfsutils-linux.                                                                                                                                                                                 
Preparing to unpack .../zfsutils-linux_0.7.12-2+deb10u2_arm64.deb ...                                                                                                                                                                   
Unpacking zfsutils-linux (0.7.12-2+deb10u2) ...                                                                                                                                                                                         
Selecting previously unselected package zfs-zed.
Preparing to unpack .../zfs-zed_0.7.12-2+deb10u2_arm64.deb ...                                                                                                                                                                 
Unpacking zfs-zed (0.7.12-2+deb10u2) ...                                                                                                                                                                                                
Setting up zfsutils-linux (0.7.12-2+deb10u2) ...                                                                                                                                                                                        
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zfs-import.target.wants/zfs-import-cache.service → /lib/systemd/system/zfs-import-cache.service.                                                                                                    
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service.wants/zfs-import.target → /lib/systemd/system/zfs-import.target.                                                                                                                  
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zfs.target.wants/zfs-import.target → /lib/systemd/system/zfs-import.target.                                                                                                                         
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zfs-share.service.wants/zfs-mount.service → /lib/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service.                                                                                                                  
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zfs.target.wants/zfs-mount.service → /lib/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service.                                                                                                                         
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zfs.target.wants/zfs-share.service → /lib/systemd/system/zfs-share.service.                                                                                                                         
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/zfs.target → /lib/systemd/system/zfs.target.                                                                                                                                
zfs-import-scan.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.                                                                                                                                                                
Job for zfs-mount.service failed because the control process exited with error code.                                                                                                                                                    
See "systemctl status zfs-mount.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.                                                                                                                                                              
invoke-rc.d: initscript zfs-mount, action "start" failed.                                                                                                                                                                               
● zfs-mount.service - Mount ZFS filesystems                                                                                                                                                                                             
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)                                                                                                                                              
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-06-19 17:17:06 BST; 15ms ago                                                                                                                                                       
     Docs: man:zfs(8)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  Process: 7114 ExecStart=/sbin/zfs mount -a (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)                                                                                                                                                            
 Main PID: 7114 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Jun 19 17:17:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Mount ZFS filesystems...                                                                                                                                                               
Jun 19 17:17:06 raspberrypi zfs[7114]: The ZFS modules are not loaded.                                                                                                                                                                  
Jun 19 17:17:06 raspberrypi zfs[7114]: Try running '/sbin/modprobe zfs' as root to load them.                                                                                                                                           
Jun 19 17:17:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE                                                                                                                           
Jun 19 17:17:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.                                                                                                                                              
Jun 19 17:17:06 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Mount ZFS filesystems.                                                                                                                                                          
dpkg: error processing package zfsutils-linux (--configure):                                                                                                                                                                            
 installed zfsutils-linux package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1                                                                                                                                      
Setting up zfs-dkms (0.7.12-2+deb10u2) ...                                                                                                                                                                                              
Loading new zfs-0.7.12 DKMS files...                                                                                                                                                                                                    
It is likely that 5.4.42-v8+ belongs to a chroot's host                                                                                                                                                                                 
Building for 4.19.0-9-arm64, 5.4.42+, 5.4.42-v7+, 5.4.42-v7l+ and 5.4.42-v8+                                                                                                                                                            
Building initial module for 4.19.0-9-arm64                                                                                                                                                                                              
Done.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
zavl.ko:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Running module version sanity check.                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 - Original module                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   - No original module exists within this kernel                                                                                                                                                                                       
 - Installation                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.19.0-9-arm64/updates/dkms/                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
znvpair.ko:                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Running module version sanity check.                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 - Original module                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   - No original module exists within this kernel                                                                                                                                                                                       
 - Installation                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.19.0-9-arm64/updates/dkms/                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
zunicode.ko:                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Running module version sanity check.                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 - Original module                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.19.0-9-arm64/updates/dkms/

zcommon.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.19.0-9-arm64/updates/dkms/

zfs.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.19.0-9-arm64/updates/dkms/

zpios.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.19.0-9-arm64/updates/dkms/

icp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.19.0-9-arm64/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
Module build for kernel 5.4.42+ was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Module build for kernel 5.4.42-v7+ was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Module build for kernel 5.4.42-v7l+ was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Module build for kernel 5.4.42-v8+ was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zfs-zed:
 zfs-zed depends on zfsutils-linux (>= 0.7.12-2+deb10u2); however:
  Package zfsutils-linux is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package zfs-zed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (241-7~deb10u4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 zfsutils-linux
 zfs-zed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I think I would need to install ZFS from source.
According to the guides I've looked at for doing this:

- https://lunar.computer/posts/zfs-source-on-arm64/
- https://gist.github.com/mohakshah/b203d33a235307c40065bdc43e287547

I need the linux kernel headers to build ZFS from source but I can't get the kernel headers prepared with any of the methods i've seen.
Neither `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.4.42-v8
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-5.4.42-v8'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-5.4.42-v8'
```

nor `sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers`:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  raspberrypi-kernel-headers:armhf
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/24.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 163 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package raspberrypi-kernel-headers:armhf.
(Reading database ... 110181 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../raspberrypi-kernel-headers_1.20200601-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking raspberrypi-kernel-headers:armhf (1.20200601-1) ...
Setting up raspberrypi-kernel-headers:armhf (1.20200601-1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.19.118+
configure: error: *** Unable to build an empty module.
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.19.118+ (aarch64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/spl/0.7.12/build/make.log for more information.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.19.118-v7+
configure: error: *** Unable to build an empty module.
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.19.118-v7+ (aarch64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/spl/0.7.12/build/make.log for more information.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.19.118-v7l+
configure: error: *** Unable to build an empty module.
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.19.118-v7l+ (aarch64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/spl/0.7.12/build/make.log for more information.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.19.118-v8+
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.19.118-v8+ cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.19.118-v8+ package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
```

...successfully fetches the linux headers.

I also get an error when I download the kernel source from: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/releases/tag/raspberrypi-kernel_1.20200601%2Barm64-1 and attempt to prepare them myself following
this post: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=255571

`make bcm2711_defconfig` throws an error:

```
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/confdata.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/expr.o
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c
/bin/sh: 1: flex: not found
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:9: scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c] Error 127
make: *** [Makefile:567: bcm2711_defconfig] Error 2
```

Any help either installing ubuntu 20.04 with USB boot or ZFS on raspberry pi OS 64bit would be much appreciated!

Comment: *"It is likely that 5.4.42-v8+ belongs to a chroot's host"* (from your install errors) is an interesting message.  Do you know what chroot is? Is this part of the context? If so you should indicate it.  In any case, edit in the output from `uname -r` and `ls /lib/modules`.   WRT the `make` error at the end (actually from the shell): *"/bin/sh: 1: flex: not found"* -> `apt install flex`